# XSLT not changing the XML at all

Tags: xml, xslt

I get that error : Error while transforming to XSLT . Invalid value of an attribute in XSLT 1.0.
I m new to XSLT and XML so forgive my ignorance , but I searched for error , but didnt found it . I get this error only in mozilla , in IE it is modifuing the XML only with CSS file completely ignoring the XSLT . 
So , here is my code both of XML and XSLT :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="pti_project.css"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="pti_projec.xslt"?>
<people>
    <employee>
        <name>Ivan</name>
        <family>Ivanov</family>
        <number>0928345768</number>
        <section>1</section>
        <salary>1200</salary>
        <yearofbirth>1997</yearofbirth>
        <numchildren>3</numchildren>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <name>Petar</name>
        <family>Ivanov</family>
        <number>0384578394</number>
        <section>2</section>
        <salary>800</salary>
        <yearofbirth>1990</yearofbirth>
        <numchildren>1</numchildren>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <name>Sierra</name>
        <family>Sierra</family>
        <number>0398493821</number>
        <section>1</section>
        <salary>1100</salary>
        <yearofbirth>1999</yearofbirth>
        <numchildren>0</numchildren>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <name>Cayla</name>
        <family>Siver</family>
        <number>0232452875</number>
        <section>1</section>
        <salary>1300</salary>
        <yearofbirth>1999</yearofbirth>
        <numchildren>0</numchildren>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <name>Sara</name>
        <family>Silver</family>
        <number>0723845377</number>
        <section>2</section>
        <salary>1500</salary>
        <yearofbirth>1991</yearofbirth>
        <numchildren>3</numchildren>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <name>Mark</name>
        <family>Goldenberg</family>
        <number>0932834571</number>
        <section>2</section>
        <salary>700</salary>
        <yearofbirth>1989</yearofbirth>
        <numchildren>2</numchildren>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <name>Henry</name>
        <family>Siver</family>
        <number>0837465737</number>
        <section>2</section>
        <salary>1400</salary>
        <yearofbirth>1994</yearofbirth>
        <numchildren>0</numchildren>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <name>Bobbie</name>
        <family>Silver</family>
        <number>0654739725</number>
        <section>3</section>
        <salary>1000</salary>
        <yearofbirth>1997</yearofbirth>
        <numchildren>3</numchildren>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <name>Pennie</name>
        <family>River</family>
        <number>0832888216</number>
        <section>3</section>
        <salary>650</salary>
        <yearofbirth>1999</yearofbirth>
        <numchildren>0</numchildren>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <name>Leonardo</name>
        <family>Splinter</family>
        <number>0832838477</number>
        <section>3</section>
        <salary>1800</salary>
        <yearofbirth>1995</yearofbirth>
        <numchildren>2</numchildren>
    </employee>
</people>
```

And this is XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
    <body>
        <table border="2">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Name:
                </th>
                <th>
                    Family:
                </th>
                <th>
                    Number:
                </th>
                <th>
                    Section:
                </th>
                <th>
                    Salary:
                </th>
                <th>
                    Year of birth:
                </th>
                <th>
                    Number of children:
                </th>
            </tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="people/employee">
            <xsl:sort select="name" data-type="text" order="acsending"/>
            <tr>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="salary&gt;200">
                        <td color="green">
                            <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="family"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="number"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="section"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="salary"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="yearofbirth"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="numchildren"/>
                        </td>
                    </xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Sorry for posting so much .

Comment: Are you sure that your XSL is being served?  Enter the URL in your browser.  It's really better to transform server side, you have much more control, and fewer browser inconsistencies.

Comment: Sorry for me being dumb , but I have little knowedge because our teacher showed us only one way to do it and base is older in my school . So to enter this URL in browser : http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform . The namespace ?? Or you meant something else @William Walseth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change:

```
order="acsending"
```

to:

```
order="ascending"
```

---

You also need a better testing tool.

---

P.S. Note also that `color` is not a valid attribute of `td`.  But that's not related to XSLT.

Comment: Yes , I m using notepad++ . It might be funny to you :D . That was my error , one mistaken letter .... :(

Answer (score -1):

You can't use < and > inside an xml/xsl document except to delimit tags. This:

```
<xsl:when test="salary>200">
```

should be:

```
<xsl:when test="salary&gt;200">
```

Comment: Good catch, if you were running this on server, you'd get an error when loading the transformation.

Comment: No, it is not a "good catch". There is absolutely nothing wrong with `test="salary>200"`. @WilliamWalseth